# Can I combine these two regexes into one?

Tags: regex, perl

My application's database records have ten-digit IDs, and a null value may be indicated either by `""` or by `"0000000000"`. Currently, I use the following idiom to check for valid IDs:

```perl
my $is_valid = $id =~ m/[0-9]{10}/ && $id =~ /[1-9]/;
```

The first regex checks the overall format, and the second one rules out the  `"0000000000"` value by looking for a non-null digit somewhere in the string. I was curious whether I can combine these two regexes into one.

That one regex will probably be less efficient, but as I said, I'm just curious if it's doable at all.

Comment: It should be two conditions it has numbers and not only zeros. Worth asking anyway, someone might bring something totally unexpected.

Comment: Since `"0000000000"` is actually 10 digits, it can never match `[0-9]{11}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This calls for a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (regex broken down into multiple lines for clarity):

```
if ($id =~ 
    m/\A      # Anchor the match to the start of the string
    (?!0*\z)  # Assert that it's impossible to match only zeroes until end-of-str
    [0-9]{10} # Match exactly 10 digits
    \z        # Anchor the match to the end of the string
    /x)       # (verbose regex)
    {
    # Successful match
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm aware of look-ahead/behind assertions, but I would not have come up with this particular pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious how you have managed to match 10 digit IDs with

```
my $is_valid = $id =~ m/[0-9]{11}/ && $id =~ /[1-9]/;
```

..since this only matches 11 digit IDs. The `&&` operator short circuits if the first argument is false, so the second argument is never even checked.

What I would do is write a small subroutine to handle validation:

```
sub is_valid_id {
    my $id   = shift;
    return 0 if (length($id) != 10);           # assert length
    return 0 unless $id =~ /^[0-9]+$/;         # assert numeric
    return 0 unless $id =~ /[1-9]/;            # assert at least 1 non-zero digit
    return 1;
}
```

This might seem overly verbose, but I think it is a good idea in this case to state each requirement in a clear manner.

As for curiosity, I think Tim Pietzcker has found the regex to combine the two.

Comment: +1 for insisting on clarity. And I corrected the 11<->10 typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use regexp to check for constant string? Just compare them instead:

```
my $is_valid = $id =~ m/[0-9]{11}/ && $id ne "0000000000";
```

Comment: Hm, I think that's historical. I used to rely on the string being numerical and just checked `$id =~ /[1-9]/`.

Answer (score -1):

`/0{0}[1-9][0-9]{10}|0{1}[1-9][0-9]{9}|0{2}[1-9][0-9]{8}|...|0{10}[1-9][0-9]{0}/`

Comment: Okay, that's the brute-force answer. ;-)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I tried to demonstrate the idea, not to write a valid regex. Sorry if it is not directly ready for executing: my text editor does not highlight regex syntax errors.

Comment: OK, let me put it another way: What do you expect `0{0}` to do?

Comment: Good try, what OP asked for. But in terms of performance, worse than OP's solution. If no better solution, OP has to accept this as solution. :)

Comment: OP said: "That one regex will probably be less efficient, but as I said, I'm just curious if it's doable at all."

Answer (score -1):

much easier just to check if **$id>0**
but if you want regexp try this one

```
my $is_valid = $id =~ /0*[1-9]+/;
```

but both variants are not checking if $id have exactly 11 digits.

Comment: It will also not consider valid the ids like `10` for example.

Comment: penartur: It considers it valid, because the regex is not anchored to the string end. On a more general note, this solution is not better (i.e. it does not accept less and reject more) than `/[1-9]/` since e.g. `0*` may match nothing.

Comment: anyway i think **my $is_valid = $id > 0**  is faster and better,
even **if($id) { print 'correct' }** should work because both "0000" and ""  == false